# How i can add github/local dependencies with Boot (clojure)

Tags: clojure, boot-clj

For instance i want to fork some existing clojar, extend it and use in my project.

How i can do this w/o pushing to clojars/maven?

Interested in both options: link to github and local path.

Thanks!

UPD

What i want is to include some existing Clojure project as dependency, similar like ruby gem allows. 
Is this possible with Boot? Or i always need to compile to java?

Comment: Maybe this could help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-in-maven-project

Comment: Not much, what i want is to include some existing Clojure project as dependency, similar like ruby gem allows. Is this possible with Boot? Or i always need to compile to java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I have setup my fork of `castra` on the `castra-simple` example for hoplon.

https://github.com/hoplon/demos/tree/master/castra-simple

open shell

`git clone castra:repo`

in castra dir

file: `build.boot`

```clj
; ...
(def +version+ "3.0.0-SNAPSHOT")
; ...
```

`boot watch build-jar`

open new shell

`git clone castra-simple:repo`

in castra-simple

file: `boot.build`

```clj
(set-env!
 :dependencies
 '[
   ;; ...
   [hoplon/castra             "3.0.0-SNAPSHOT"] ;;forked repo
   ;; ...
   ]
 :source-paths   #{"src"}
 :resource-paths #{"assets"})

;; ...

(deftask dev
  "Build castra-simple for local development."
  []
  (comp
   (serve
    :handler 'app.handler/app
    :reload true
    :port 8000)
   (watch) (speak) (hoplon) (reload) (cljs-repl) (cljs)

   ;;forked repo
   (checkout :dependencies '[[hoplon/castra "3.0.0-SNAPSHOT"]])))
```

`boot dev`

Comment: https://github.com/arachne-framework/arachne-buildtools this simplifies local/github deps

Answer (score 0):

As i figured out with Boot you can specify source-paths:

```
(set-env! :source-paths   #{"src", "../clj-mailgun/src"})
```

This is the only way to add other projects into your. (adding source-code, not .jar)

There is no way to specify github link - you should clone it manually and add to :source-paths path.

Please correct me if i am missing something.

Comment: This is getting me halfway to the solution. I am running into a problem where my library/fork has a `build.boot` file that needs to be has some deps of it's own that aren't being found by my main `build.boot` file.

Comment: I have talked with micha about this, and he suggests using `boot checkout -h` which is supposed to be for this situation.

Comment: @PPPaul boot checkout seems deprecated now, would you know what replaces it ?